# How to Upload Multiple Images from HTML from to FIles?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, image-uploading

I am trying to upload multiple files from HTML form to a folder and storing information in my database. I have written the following code, but it is not working correctly. If I upload 1 image and left the other two Image fields,then it stores 3 images of same name and same Image and if I upload 3 different Images in three difference fields then it takes only the last image and replace others with it, and shows the same image for all.

Kindly guide me.

```
HTML Image Fields

<file> <Image2> <Image3>
```

PHP CODE

```
        /*-------------------
        IMAGE QUERY 
        ---------------*/
        $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
    $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));


    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"]   == "image/gif")
    ||  ($_FILES["image2"]["type"]  == "image/gif")
    ||  ($_FILES["image3"]["type"]  == "image/gif")
    ||  ($_FILES["file"]["type"]    == "image/jpeg")
    ||  ($_FILES["image2"]["type"]  == "image/jpeg")
    ||  ($_FILES["image3"]["type"]  == "image/jpeg")
    ||  ($_FILES["file"]["type"]    == "image/jpg")
    ||  ($_FILES["image2"]["type"]  == "image/jpg")
    ||  ($_FILES["image3"]["type"]  == "image/jpg")
    ||  ($_FILES["file"]["type"]    == "image/pjpeg")
    ||  ($_FILES["image2"]["type"]  == "image/pjpeg")
    ||  ($_FILES["image3"]["type"]  == "image/pjpeg")
    ||  ($_FILES["file"]["type"]    == "image/x-png")
    ||  ($_FILES["image2"]["type"]  == "image/x-png")
    ||  ($_FILES["image3"]["type"]  == "image/x-png")
    ||  ($_FILES["file"]["type"]    == "image/png")
    ||  ($_FILES["image2"]["type"]  == "image/png")
    ||  ($_FILES["image3"]["type"]  == "image/png"))
    //&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 200000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))

      {
      if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0 && $_FILES["image"]["error"] > 0)
        {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
        }
      else
        {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 200000) . " kB<br>";

        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["image2"]["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["image2"]["type"] . "<br>";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["image2"]["size"] / 200000) . " kB<br>";




            $image_name=        $_FILES["file"]["name"];  
            $random_name=       rand().$_FILES["file"]["name"];


            $image_name2=       $_FILES["image2"]["name"];  
            $random_name2=      rand().$_FILES["image2"]["name"];


            $image_name3=       $_FILES["image3"]["name"];  
            $random_name3=      rand().$_FILES["image3"]["name"];






            $path=              move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                                        "upload/products/" . $random_name);


            $path2=             move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image2"]["tmp_name"],
                                        "upload/products/" . $random_name);     


            $path3=             move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image3"]["tmp_name"],
                                        "upload/products/" . $random_name); 



             $folder="upload/products/" .$random_name;  

             $folder2="upload/products/" .$random_name; 

             $folder3="upload/products/" .$random_name; 




                //echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" .rand(). $_FILES["file"]["name"];  
                echo "Stored in:    "."upload/products/". $random_name;

          /*
                $sql = "INSERT INTO `category_images` (`image_name`,`image_location`) VALUES 
                    ('".$image_name."', '".$path."')";
            */      



                $sql = "Insert into product_images (product_id,name,images) 
                    VALUES ($current_id,'$image_name', '$folder')";


                $sql2 = "Insert into product_images (product_id,name,images) 
                    VALUES ($current_id,'$image_name2', '$folder2')";


                $sql3 = "Insert into product_images (product_id,name,images) 
                    VALUES ($current_id,'$image_name3', '$folder3')";

                $result = mysql_query($sql);
                mysql_query($sql2);
                mysql_query($sql3);

                if ($result)
                 {

                    echo "successfull"; 
                 } 
                 else {
                        echo mysql_error();
        }


          }
        }

    else
      {
      echo "Invalid file";
      }


        /*-----------------
        IMAGE QUERY END
        ------------------*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For uploading multiple files its better to use input field names as array, so the uploaded files will be well organized as an array that can be easily handled. So your upload form should look something like this

`<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Image1:  <input name="image[]" type="file" /><br />
Image2:  <input name="image[]" type="file" /><br />
Image3:  <input name="image[]" type="file" /><br />
Image4:  <input name="image[]" type="file" /><br />
Image5:  <input name="image[]" type="file" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>`

And in the upload.php

```
if($_FILES['image'])
{
//organise the array :: refer http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php for more details
$images = reArrayFiles($_FILES['image']);
$image_count = count($_FILES['image']['name']);
for ($i = 0; $i < $image_count; $i++)
{
    if($images[$i]['name']!='' && $images[$i]['tmp_name']!='')
    {

        $path = 'upload/products/';
        $saved = 0;
        # Upload file to folder
        $filename = basename($images[$i]['tmp_name']);
        $filename_array = explode('.', $filename);
        $ext = strtolower(end($filename_array));
                    $image_name = date('YmdHis').'.'.$ext; //random file naming
        if(in_array(strtoupper($ext), $allowed_ext)) { 
            $folder = $path . $image_name;
            $saved = move_uploaded_file($images[$i]['tmp_name'], $folder);
        } 
        if($saved)
        {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO product_images (product_id,name,images) VALUES ($current_id,'$image_name', '$folder')";
            if(mysql_query($sql))
                echo "successfull"; 
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Failed to upload file';
        }
    }
}
}

function rearrange( $arr ){
foreach( $arr as $key => $all ){
    foreach( $all as $i => $val ){
        $new[$i][$key] = $val;   
    }   
}
return $new;
}
```